# Where can I find the correct HTTP endpoints for testing Google Ads API calls in Oauth2 Playground?

Tags: google-ads-api, oauth2-playground

There are only a few RPC methods that include the HTTP reference endpoint in the reference documentation.

I got the Google Ads Service's Mutate method to work with
https://googleads.googleapis.com/v3/customers/{customer-id}/googleAds:mutate

However, trying to call the Keyword Plan Idea service fails, reporting there is no such URL on the server:

https://googleads.googleapis.com/v2/customers/{customer-id}/keywordPlanIdea:generateKeywordIdeas

I have tried it with and without the customers/{customer-id}, and with GET, POST, and even PUT. No luck.

Does anyone know the correct endpoint?

Thanks!

John

Comment: This is very frustrating. Either they should have SDKs in all the major languages  (nodejs/JS) or they should expose the API endpoints simply

Answer (score 0):

For `generateKeywordIdeas`, the URL endpoint is
`https://googleads.googleapis.com/v6/customers/{customer-id}/generateKeywordIdeas`

This information is listed here: https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/ads/googleads/v6/services/keyword_plan_idea_service.proto

Specifically, this code from that file:

```
  rpc GenerateKeywordIdeas(GenerateKeywordIdeasRequest) returns (GenerateKeywordIdeaResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v6/customers/{customer_id=*}:generateKeywordIdeas"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
```

You can find the endpoints for all other Google Ads services in this way, by going here: https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/ads/googleads/v6/services

However, this doesn't tell you the request payload format. For that, I suggest looking into their API clients, like this: https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/blob/master/examples/Planning/GenerateKeywordIdeas.php. You can run some of those examples and inspect the network to see how the request is structured.